# Issues with URLs in Django 3 when trying to view products detail page

Tags: python, django, django-urls

New to Django and im trying to simply get to my products detail page using the following code in my URLs.py:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from products import views
import carts
from carts.views import CartView
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('products/', views.all, name='products'),
    path('s/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('products/<slug:slug>', views.single, name='single_product'), <----This is the page I want to get to
    path('cart/', carts.views.CartView, name='cart'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If its any help, this is the link I use in my template to get to the product display page `<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>`

**And here is my view:**

```
def single(request, slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
        images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product)
        context = {'product': product, "images": images}
        template = 'products/single.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    except:
        raise Http404
```

But when trying to access this page I get the following 404 Error:
[image]

Maybe a fresh pair of eyes can help me spot the mistake I'm making?

If any additional info is needed please let me know, I'll be happy to provide. Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: try moving `path('products/<slug:slug>', views.single, name='single_product')` above `path('products/', views.all, name='products'),`

Comment: @TomWojcik - Thanks for the response Tom. I tried moving the ```products<slug:slug>...``` path above the the other but still no luck there either. It returns the same error 404 page.

Comment: hm, then maybe replace `'products/<slug:slug>` with `'products/<slug:slug>/`

Comment: I tried this too, unfortunately, still no luck. Could it possible be something to do with my Imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try replacing:

```
    path('products/<slug:slug>', views.single, name='single_product'),
```

with

```
    path('products/<slug:slug>/', views.single, name='single_product'),
```

Django automatically appends a slash (/) to the end of urls by default and the image you showed us shows an url ending on a slash while your defined path does not contain one. I just tried to reproduce it, and this made it work.

**And then if it still doesn't work, double check if you are using the correct slug to find your Product using the shell** as you are raising a 404 whenever an exception occurs. You might even consider removing the try/except to check if it's actually raising a different exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the last slash ('/') is the problem, try the url without it:
http://127.0.0.1/products/product-one

Comment: @khsodier - Thanks for the response. I tried the URL without the slash but still no luck unfortunately. I get the same error 404 page.

Comment: If the rest of the urls work fine, have you tried without adding the type in the parameter?.

Comment: I tried this too but the page failed as it could no longer find the correct product to display

Comment: If its any help, this is the link I use in my template to get to the product display page ```<a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>```